# about the returned Socket object from SocketServer

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I have a very simple question, however I am confused by a tutorial.

Say, I create a server & use port 1234:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1234);
```

Then, I ask server to wait for requests by:

```
while(true) {
  // is the returned socket represents the server side socket or client side socket???
  Socket socket = server.accept();
}
```

My question is whether the socket returned by `server.accept()` a server side socket or client side socket? It is not very well explained in [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()).

The reason why I ask this question is because when I run `socket.getPort()`, it **doesn't** return server port 1234, instead, it returns a port not defined by me, so, I am thinking it might be the client's socket. But I am not sure.

Comment: It's in the server. It's a server socket. You should have called `getLocalport()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. The
>   method blocks until a connection is made.

which means, that it is server.

`socket.getPort()` according to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html),

> Returns the remote port number to which this socket is connected.

Comment: But run my code, with socket.getport() it doesn't return server port 1234, it returns a port I haven't defined, it sounds like it returns client's socket.

Answer (score 0):

A Socket has two ends, where one end will send information to the other end with the OutputStream, and receive information from the other end with the InputStream. See also getInputStream() and getOutputStream() methods on the Socket.

In your terms, you can consider the socket to be server side because the InputStream is receiving information from the client that has connected to the server, and the OutputStream is sending information to the client.

Typically once the socket is obtained with the server.accept() method, a thread, created with the socket you obtained, should be used for communicating with the client, so that your server can handle multiple clients at the same time.